# Difference when output is array or square brackets

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to understand what is the difference (if there's any) between those two outputs.

```
array([array([203., 164.,  87., ...,   1.,   1.,   0.]),
       array([39., 44., 40., ..., 40., 30., 21.]),
       array([152., 144., 133., ...,  36.,  36.,  36.])], dtype=object)
```

And

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  5., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ..., 10.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ..., 16.,  9.,  0.],
       ...,
       [ 0.,  0.,  1., ...,  6.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  2., ..., 12.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0., 10., ..., 12.,  1.,  0.]])
```

To me, both these structures are 2D arrays. But for some reason, one of them is printed differently.

I'm trying to feed the first structure to a complex function (`svm.SVC.fit`). The second one works, but the first one doesn't:

> setting an array element with a sequence

although they seem to be the exact same to me ..

Comment: @chepner if I write `type(firstArray[0])` or `type(secondArray[0])` they both yield `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: Mmmh .. `type(firstArray[0][0])` and `type(secondArray[0][0])` are both `numpy.float64`

Comment: " the first one doesn't, ": what happens? error? wrong results?

Comment: It complains that I'm `setting an array element with a sequence.`. But before trying to understand this message, I'd like to understand if both these outputs are different at all. If they are, I'll be able to fix the second one to correspond to the first, and the error should go away

Comment: It looks like whatever produced the first array returned the array of array objects whereas the second one returned the array of array values. the error in your comment is suggesting that it is trying to read in `array([...])` as opposed to `[...]`.

Comment: Your first example contains arrays with varying lengths, which numpy does not deal with well, which is why it coerces it to an `(n, )` shape array of `dtype` object

Comment: Okay, indeed, that was because of array varying in length .. If anyone posts this as answer, I'll accept it

Comment: yeah, we need an answer for that one.

Comment: @ArthurAttout I posted my comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in my comment, they are *not* both 2D arrays.  The first is a 1D array of shape `(N, )`.  You are trying to create a numpy array with variable length subarrays.  When this happens, numpy coerces the type of the array to `object` and makes it one dimensional.  **You should avoid this at all costs**, at it removes many of the benefits to using `numpy` in the first place.

A common approach is padding the subarrays so they are all a uniform length, but whatever you do, you should not use `numpy` with jagged arrays.